# Powershell: Comparing a block of text to a file

Tags: powershell

It certainly seemed like a simple enough task but for whatever reason this doesn't work:

```
    #Verifies that the firefox proxy setting have been applied

    #locate Prefsjs file
    $PrefsFiles = Get-Item -Path ($env:SystemDrive+"\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*\prefs.js")

    #read in Prefsjs
    $Prefsjs = (Get-Content $PrefsFiles)

    #Block to compare 
    $Update= @"
    user_pref("network.proxy.http", "0.0.0.0");
    user_pref("network.proxy.http_port", 80);
    "@

    ($Prefsjs -contains $Update)
```

The last line should return a true because the text actually does exist in $Prefsjs... Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I've written out $Update and $Prefsjs to files and looked at them in Notepad++. Both have each line terminated with a carriage return and line feed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not going to match because you're comparing a multi-line string to an array of single line strings.

You need to compare like objects, which means $Prefsjs also needs to be a single, multi-line string.  The easiest way to do that is to add the -Raw switch to your `Get-Content`:

```
#read in Prefsjs
    $Prefsjs = (Get-Content $PrefsFiles -Raw)
```

But now $Prefsjs is not an array any more, so you can't use `-Contains`. It's now just a single string, so you can use the string `contains()` method to accomplish the same thing:

```
$Prefsjs.contains($Update)
```

Comment: That works! Thanks! (It seems that every time something looks like it SHOULD work, but doesn't, it's because of a type mismatch.)